# How can I force my site to serve just HTTPS and non-www?

Tags: redirects, apache, wordpress, https, no-www

I have a WordPress install where all the links are `https://example.com`. So, users that try to access the site via `https://www.example.com` will see the site, but none of the images and resources will load.

How do I force all users to be redirected to the same domain? I'd rather have everyone at `https://example.com`.

Is this something I can do through the domain's DNS settings, in the host/server, or in WordPress itself?

**Update:**
I am using Apache.

**Update 2:**

All the conditions I am trying to catch:

User types,

1. `http://example.com`
2. `http://www.example.com`
3. `https://example.com`
4. `https://www.example.com`
5. `example.com`
6. `www.example.com`

As I understand, conditions 5 and 6 should be the same as 1 and 2. But I put it there, just in case. Condition 3 is where I want users to go, so that should work by default.

1-6 should redirect to -> `https://example.com`

Answer (score 4):

What webserver are you running on?

**Nginx**

To remove www in nginx do the following.

```
if ($host = 'www.example.com' ) {
    rewrite  ^/(.*)$  http://example.com/$1  permanent;
}
```

That will strip the www.

To force https:

```
rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
```

Along those lines.

**Apache**

Force https:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Strip www:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try and get back to you. I am on Apache. I should have noted that.

Comment: One warning- %{SERVER_NAME} may not always give you what you expect. Check it first. You can use PHP for this. You can always use the target domain name for this example if you need to.

Comment: Better to use a server block with Nginx like this: `server { listen 443; server_name www.example.tld; return 301 https://example.tld$request_uri; ... }` because [if is evil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil) and the official docs say "It's generally a good idea to avoid it if possible."

Comment: I think I got it to work. It's hard to say because different browsers are giving me different results. The redirect seems to work fine if the http is actually typed, but if the user only enter mydomain.com, then the user still get's the http page.

Comment: I updated my questions with all conditions that I am trying to catch.